# Android Catch Home or BackPress or KeyDown in library

Tags: android, onbackpressed

The library displays a `RelativeLayout` , how do I close this `RelativeLayout` if the user clicked the Home button

I'm trying to do the same thing it does InterstitialAd. There are no onbackpressed overrides.
How is this happend? I didn't find any information about this?

Comment: can you provide some code to make us understand more what you are trying to do?

Comment: I draw my dialog box on top of all the elements 
layout = new RelativeLayout(context);
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lp = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
                RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
context.addContentView(layout,lp);